# Matt's trick (reparametrization) makes my models slower, not faster

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, hierarchical-bayesian, stan

I am currently programming a hierarchical model in Stan. Following the advice from [section 22.7 from the Stan manual](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_23/stan-users-guide/reparameterization-section.html), I reparametrized my model so it samples the individual differences from a $N(0,1)$ standard normal instead of a $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ distribution. However, I found the model to be very slow, so I looked at the pairs plot. This plot shows severe funnels in the posterior distribution of the parameters that are sampled with the $N(0,1)$ prior. Also, the posteriors are highly correlated between subjects, which I found very surprising:

[image]

When I looked at the resulting posteriors of the variables, after they are translated from z-scores to the actual values, I found that there are neither funnels, nor the between-subject correlations. So I decided to remove Matt's trick and sample directly from the $N(\mu,\sigma)$ distributions. This sped up my models (from 13 minutes to around 2 minutes), and there are no observable funnels or correlations in the variables:

[image]

Here is my model with Matt's trick:

```
data {
  int<lower=1> N;
  int<lower=1> M;
  vector<lower=0>[N] RT;
  int<lower=1> subj[N];
  vector<lower=0,upper=1>[N] resp_l;     // 1 if the response was on the left, 0 otherwise
  vector<lower=0,upper=1>[N] incomp;     // 1 if the trial was incompatible, 0 otherwiese
  vector<lower=0,upper=1>[N] acc;        // Accuracy: correct (1) or incorrect (0) response
  real<lower=0> NDTMin;
  real<lower=0> minRT;
}

parameters {
  // Group level parameters
  real<lower=0> alpha;                              // Boundary separation
  real<lower=NDTMin,upper=minRT> tau;               // non-decision time
  real<lower=0,upper=1> beta;                       // initial bias
  real delta_mu;                                    // mean drift rate (group level)
  real<lower=0> delta_sigma;                        // variance
  real eta;

  // Individual parameters
  vector[M] delta_z;                               // difference in drift rate for eah subject (z-score)
}

transformed parameters {
  vector[N] beta_trl;   // Beta for each trial
  vector[M] delta;      // Individual drift rate, after conversion from z-score
  vector[N] delta_trl;  // Drift rate in each trial

  // initial offset should mostly depend on handedness etc.
  // i.e. a single offset towards left/right responses
  // therefore, we reverse the beta, if the response was on
  // the left
  beta_trl = beta+resp_l-2*beta*resp_l;

  delta = delta_mu + delta_sigma * delta_z;

  delta_trl = (delta[subj]+incomp*eta) .* (2*acc-1);
}

model {
  alpha       ~ normal(0,1);
  tau         ~ beta(1,1);
  beta        ~ beta(1,1);
  delta_sigma ~ cauchy(0,100);
  delta_mu    ~ normal(0,10);
  eta         ~ normal(0,10);

  // Difference from group mean is in z-score.
  // will be transformed later
  delta_z ~ normal(0,1);

  RT ~ wiener(alpha, tau, beta_trl, delta_trl);
}
```

In the second model, I just removed the `delta` as a generated parameter and directly sampled delta as

```
delta ~ normal(delta_mu,delta_sigma);
```

Is there something wrong, or is Matt's trick just not working in this case. If it's a problem with Matt's trick that makes it do the opposite of what it is supposed to do (creating funnels instead of removing them), then why is this the case here.

**EDIT**:

From looking at the distributions again, it seems as $\mu_\delta$ is distributed differently in the two posteriors. But this seems to be mostly in the tails:

```
             mean se_mean   sd  2.5%   25%   50%   75% 97.5% n_eff Rhat
alpha        1.64    0.00 0.05  1.54  1.60  1.64  1.67  1.74  2388 1.00
beta         0.50    0.00 0.01  0.48  0.49  0.50  0.50  0.51  1947 1.00
delta_mu     4.26    0.05 1.55  0.68  3.47  4.30  5.13  7.47   822 1.01
delta_sigma  3.01    0.07 1.76  1.13  1.78  2.45  3.67  7.93   730 1.00
tau          0.21    0.00 0.00  0.20  0.20  0.21  0.21  0.21  2163 1.00
eta         -0.56    0.00 0.14 -0.82 -0.66 -0.56 -0.47 -0.30  2987 1.00
```

in the model with Matt's trick, and

```
             mean se_mean   sd  2.5%   25%   50%   75% 97.5% n_eff Rhat
alpha        1.64    0.00 0.05  1.54  1.61  1.64  1.67  1.74  2136    1
beta         0.50    0.00 0.01  0.48  0.49  0.50  0.50  0.51  4318    1
delta_mu     4.26    0.06 2.06  0.08  3.47  4.37  5.20  8.14  1136    1
delta_sigma  3.59    0.12 3.59  1.11  1.83  2.62  3.99 12.09   927    1
tau          0.21    0.00 0.00  0.20  0.20  0.21  0.21  0.21  2732    1
eta         -0.56    0.00 0.14 -0.82 -0.65 -0.56 -0.47 -0.29  2796    1
```

in the model without.

Comment: There is a close vote, but I don't feel that this is a "software" question. It is a question about model parametrization, so seems to be perfectly on-topic in here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not unheard of for the centered parameterization to be better. [This post](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/centered-vs-non-centered-parameterizations/7344) on the Stan forums goes into the exact same issue. There it is suggested that

> [...] centered actually works better when you have informative data (large N relative to $\sigma$) for a particular group, while non centered is better for uninformative data (small N relative to $\sigma$)

[This post](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/partial-non-centered-parametrizations-in-stan/7104/5), linked from the one above, discusses the issue in terms of estimating a someting in groups of differing size, (ie of differing informativeness) and it is suggested that

> [...] you can gather your individual groups into "informative data" and "non-informative data", implement the former with a centered parameterization and the latter with a non-informative parameterization, and see if that improves anything.

Comment: Ok, this seems to explain one other observation I made for this model. The example above is for only four of the participants, which I tested so I can get faster model evaluations. For those four the difference is between 13 and 2 minutes. When I add the complete set of participants, then the difference is only between 20 and 10 minutes, which is much less drastic.